# Read value from property file from different location in class path

Tags: java

I have project structure like this:

- src--

  - com.adapter(Packege)

    - LoadPropfile
  - resource(folder)

    - errormessage.properties

How can I load the property file In `LoadPropfile` class residing inside
`com.adapter` package and Property file is located inside `resource` folder.
and both are inside `src` folder.

Comment: Please show us your code of what you have tried yet. And maybe you list your package-class-structure a little bit clearer.

Comment: How are you building your project (through IDE, Maven, ant, ...?), and how are you running it? If you want to load the property file from classpath you need to add the location of wherever the property file ends up during build to the runtime classpath.

Comment: Are you using Eclipse? Have you tried adding the `resource` folder as a `source` folder?

Answer (score 1):

Try using below code in your **LoadPropfile** class to read file as **InputStream**:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();           
InputStream stream = loader.getResourceAsStream("errormessage.properties"); // define properties file here
properties.load(stream);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of loading a properties file from another package:

```
InputStream propertyStream = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("errormessage.properties");
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(propertyStream);
```